# Check if browser opens window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the browser opens the popup window. In case the browser denies opening the window, I want to take some other action.

This is my example code:

```
function open_window(){
   window.open("url",_blank);
}

if(!open_window(){ 
  //action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is blocked by browser, window.open will return null. So this  function will return false.

```
function firepopup(url,width,height) {
    n=window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,titlebar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width='+width+',height='+height);
    return n==null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var winRef;    
var url = 'http://someurl';

winRef = window.open('', 'winPop', 'sampleListOfOptions');

if(winRef == null || winRef.document.location.href != url)
{
  winRef = window.open(url, 'winPop')
  //Some Another Action
}
```